# How to log _bulk api in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, amazon-ec2, bulkinsert

Currently we are using Elastic Search 5.4 and understand its deprecated version , but we have a requirement that we would need to log all the queries including the _bulk request as well , for some reason i am not seeing any logs about the _bulk requests getting logged in the log files of Elastic Search and all the search queries back and forth are getting logged , is there any reason or am i missing anything ?

Tried searching in web , tried changes in the log4j2.properties but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no real way to enable logging for bulk queries in ES for this version and hopefully this is taken care for the newer version for the newer version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).